# Re-parenting ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, activex

Is it possible in WPF to move an ActiveX control to a different place in the visual tree? I have a control that I would like to dynamically move to be the child of another widget.

If this isn't possible is there a way to make a copy of the control and place it somewhere else? My previous attempts at this have not worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an analogy, it's not a great one, but hopefully it drives the point home:

Imagine you have built a scene up using LEGOs. You also have a flat piece of aluminum with an image on it and you want to insert it under one of your LEGO layers so that it becomes part of the scene. You can't do this because there are no pegs and holes in the aluminum. It wont stick to the bottom layer and the LEGOs on top won't stick.

The analogy breaks down here because in the real world you could use glue or something to make it work.

WPF provides a single window object hosting a single DirectX surface upon which it renders each of its controls (our LEGOs above). ActiveX controls (or Winforms controls) each require a separate system window object (the aluminum plate). It's not possible to place a system window in between elements rendered on a DirectX surface.

The two technologies don't mix (or at least don't intermingle). You either have to live with this fact and arrange things with that limitation, or you need to change technologies. Either build your application with Winforms (where every control is a system window), or create/find a WPF control that provides the same functionality as this ActiveX control you're using.

Comment: @Will I wouldn't call WPF silly. It solves all of the issues that window controls have (expense, transparency, input aggravation, etc.) and it is (provided the user has a decent graphics card) able to render far more elements. The problem isn't WPF, it's that window controls are a more mature technology and as such has a vast array of useful controls developed for it.